# How to override Web.UI.Page - Events in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to compress the viewstate. Therefore I need to override `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium` wich belongs to Web.UI.Page. In "normal" ASP.Net thats quite easy but in my sharepoint-project I cannot find any place where I have a class that is inherited from Web.UI.Page

My PageLayouts have no code behind, neither has the masterPage.

The best solution would be for me to be able to handle that in a pageLayout, because I do not want every Page to cache the ViewState.

To make it a bit clearer. This is the code I want to put "somewhere":

```
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private ObjectStateFormatter _formatter = 
        new ObjectStateFormatter(); 

    protected override void
        SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _formatter.Serialize(ms, viewState);
        byte[] viewStateArray = ms.ToArray();
        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            CompressViewState.Compress(viewStateArray)));
    }
    protected override object
        LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        string vsString = Request.Form["__COMPRESSEDVIEWSTATE"];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(vsString);
        bytes = CompressViewState.Decompress(bytes);
        return _formatter.Deserialize(
            Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick idea, maybe not working. Create a delegate control that you will put in AdditionalPageHead. Check in the Init event of your control If your condition are met, and use reflection to call this protected property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would inherit from PublishingLayoutPage (which in turns way back [inherits from Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishinglayoutpage.aspx)) instead and let all of my page-layouts use this base page as codebehind.
This means you need to alter you page-layouts' page directive like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="YourNameSpace.BasePage, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```